# @Min validation on String

Tags: java, validation, annotations

In the javadoc of `@Min` (`javax.validation.constraints.Min`) it states that only numerical values can be validated.

> @Target(value={METHOD,FIELD,ANNOTATION_TYPE,CONSTRUCTOR,PARAMETER})
>   @Retention(value=RUNTIME) @Documented @Constraint(validatedBy={})
>   public @interface Min
>
> The annotated element must be a number whose value must be higher or
>   equal to the specified minimum.
>
> Supported types are:
>
> ```
> BigDecimal
> BigInteger
> byte, short, int, long, and their respective wrappers
> ```
>
> Note that double and float are not supported due to rounding errors
>   (some providers might provide some approximative support)
>
> null elements are considered valid

When I add the annotation to a String it takes the value of the String and converts it to a BigDecimal and then checks the value. As if the String contains a BigDecimal value.

Questions:

1. Where is this documented?
2. Why does Eclipse Mars not accept this?

See Eclipse (compiler) message:

> The javax.validation.constraints.Min constraint supports the following types: java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigInteger, byte, short, int, long, and their respective wrapper types.

Test.java

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

public class Test {
  @Min(10)
  String quantity;
}
```

The code works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) as implementation of the [Bean Validation API](http://beanvalidation.org/). Quoting [its documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/ch02.html#table-spec-constraints):

> BigDecimal, BigInteger, byte, short, int, long and the respective wrappers of the primitive types; Additionally supported by HV: any sub-type of CharSequence (the numeric value represented by the char sequence is evaluated), any sub-type of Number

As you correctly said in your question, the Bean Validation specification of [`@Min`](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#d0e9499) annotation does not mandate implementors to support `String` (or `CharSequence`). This is a Hibernate feature only and may not work with another implementation.

Note that in the [appendix C of the spec](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#appendix-jpa), the following is said:

> Persistence Provider should optionally recognize and try to apply the 
>   following constraints as well:
>
> - @Min / @Max on numeric columns (TODO String too?)

Comment: Thank you very much. We are using the thinclient implementation from IBM but that probably results in the same answer.